# Angular Lifecycle Hook - Constructor-initialised data loads after view init

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, lifecycle

I've loaded a firestore document and converted it to a plain js object within a component's constructor, and then accessed the object's field values within the template, which means that they're taking a second to load. As a result, even though the do render to the DOM, I get the following type of error in the browser console (here when accessing {{invoice.id}}:

> Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

From my understanding, anything defined in the constructor should be immediately available in the view when it's initialised, so why is this occurring/how can I prevent this?

**view-invoice.component.html:**

```
<h4 class="page-title">Invoice Summary</h4>

<p>ID: {{ invoice.invoiceId }}</p>
<p>Reference: {{ invoice.reference }}</p>
<p>Date: {{ invoice.date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</p>
```

**view-invoice.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { InvoiceService } from '../invoice.service';
import { Invoice } from '../invoiceModel';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-view-invoice',
  templateUrl: './view-invoice.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./view-invoice.component.scss']
})

export class ViewInvoiceComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {    
  userId: string;

  invoiceId: any;
  //    invoice: Observable<Invoice>;
  invoice: any;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private invoiceService: InvoiceService, private db: AngularFirestore, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.userId = this.authService.user.uid;

    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.invoiceId = params.id;
    })

  this.db.collection('/users').doc(this.userId).collection('/invoices')
  .doc(this.invoiceId).ref.get().then(snapshot => {
        const data = snapshot.data();
        this.invoice = data;
    })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getInvoice();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {       
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the relevant code snippet?

Comment: Sorry, got ahead of myself there

Comment: Is it possible that your data is retrieved asynchronously and you need to use the async pipe?

Comment: Just tried using the async pipe like this but it's supposedly invalid: 
<p>ID: {{ (invoice | async)?.invoiceId }}</p>

Comment: try to move this this.getInvoice(); in ngAfterViewInit. Your code is not working because you are getting the invoiceId using subscribe which mean that your next call(this.db.collection('/users')) could get executed before you get the InvoiceId.  Hence move the both getInvoice and this.db.collection('/users').doc(this.userId).collection('/invoices')
  .doc(this.invoiceId).ref.get().then(snapshot => ....) inside ngAfterViewInit and also put a if condition using InvoiceId so only this this.db.collection('/users').... executes after you get invoice id.

Comment: The getInvoice callback isn't relevant, it was just left over from a previous method that's been removed, so shouldn't be affecting this

Comment: If i read it correctly it is saying your params are undefined. Did you check if they really are undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part of code that's responsible for fetching invoice data is asynchronous. Therefore, while the method is called in the constructor, the response can be (and almost always will be) unavailable when HTML template is rendered. There's a few ways to prevent this. One of them is to simply wrap HTML tags in `ng-container` which will be rendered only after data is available:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="invoice">
  <p>ID: {{ invoice.invoiceId }}</p>
  <p>Reference: {{ invoice.reference }}</p>
  <p>Date: {{ invoice.date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</p>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: @nick.cook How this is different from my comment in upper section since I also wrote that your subscribe function might not give you data while component gets initialized?

Comment: Because you were saying that a function callback for a function that didn't exist anywhere in the code needed to be moved, and I even said to you that this was irrelevant and left over after the function was deleted. This had no effect on anything else